# How to create a bootable HDD DOS partition

Tags: windows-7, ms-dos

There is a desktop with Windows7 that has no CD-ROM.
The FAT32 partition was created with 100Mb (Megabytes) of space.
When computer starts, I would like to be able to boot in MS-DOS or so (no Windows, but to run old programs under MS-DOS).

Unfortunately, `format /S` command doesn't work as I'm in Windows7 64bit.

How to make it done without CD-ROM and without USB ports, but with Internet access?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a MS-DOS environment, you'll need access to actual MS-DOS setup files (most likely as floppy images); simply creating a bootable MS-DOS partition isn't enough, you'll have to actually *install* MS-DOS in it.

---

As a side note, I'd suggest using a virtual machine instead of trying to run MS-DOS on a modern computer; this has two main advantages:

1. It's a lot simpler to setup.
2. You don't need to reboot your computer to run MS-DOS, you'll simply start the VM and stop it when it's no longer needed.

However, even with a virtual machine, you'll *still* need an actual copy of MS-DOS (or any operating system you want to run) to install in it.

Comment: Sorry for reasking. Could you please explain, what are the steps in my situation? Still not clear is it possible or not. I have an Internet. Thank you very much.

Comment: It can be done, but it's quite complex to make MS-DOS run on a recent computer; a virtual machine would be a lot simpler to configure and use. But you'd still need a MS-DOS copy.

Comment: There's always FreeDOS, too, which should run virtually everything you might want.

Comment: There's also Dos Box.

Comment: Virtual machine option doesn't work for me as I need to do some things for system disc C where Windows 7 is located (yes, that's NTFS) from my bootable HDD logical disc (yes, HDD, not USB or CD-ROM).

Comment: You can't access NTFS from MS-DOS...